# Mysql при установке не спрашивает root пароль

Tags: mysql

ОС - Ubuntu v16.04

Ставлю mysql сервер(5.7), но при установке **не выводит диалоговое окно и не спрашивает root пароль**.

Вопрос: **C чем это связано и как решить проблему?**

Ставить более раннюю версию может?

Comment: когда последний раз ставил mysql он генерировал временный пароль и выводил его не давая возможности его задать, возможно в этом проблема?

Comment: Проблема оказалась что при установке нового mysql не удалилась полностью старая версия и пароль от рута остался прежним